# How would I best go about identifying specific objects when I come across them again?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiontask

Take NSURLSession's task objects:

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration] delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];

NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask1 = [session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://i.imgur.com/RARAP1J.jpg"]];
```

If I was in the following delegate method:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    ....
```

If I ended up creating a bunch of `NSURLSessionDataTasks`, how would I go about checking which one `dataTask` refers to. Sure, I could have a bunch of properties, but if I have 50 tasks, that gets unruly and I'd like to be able to automatically set it up in code.

I know of the `taskIdentifier` method, which would work, but it's `readonly` and I want to be able to set it.

Answer (score 0):

You can put any string you like in `NSURLSessionTask.description`. I even use `NSJSONSerialization` to stuff `NSDictionary`s there. (Ask in the comments, and I'll post the code). I can verify that this survives the backgrounding serialization of tasks.

You could also just keep a `NSMutableDictionary` ivar in your class, mapping `taskIdentifier` => arbitrary info, and removing the entry when the task is complete.